# Animate square div into trapezoid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As title states, I am trying to animate a square div into a trapezoid using jquery .animate(). However, the only animation I am getting is the width adjustment and I am not quite sure why this is occuring.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.square').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            borderRight: '100px solid red',
            borderTop: '50px solid transparent',
            borderBottom: '50px solid transparent',
            height: '100px',
            width: '0'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
div.square {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
div.left {
 border-right: 100px solid red;
 border-top: 50px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
 height: 100px;
 width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>


<div class="left"></div>
```

Comment: I belive problem is in `border: transparent` animation. If I'm not mistaken, adding jQuery UI plugin should solve this.

Comment: well running the code snippet, doesn't do anything apart from showing a square and trapezoid together and after a few seconds the square slides left & goes away.

Comment: I think @Artanis is right: from http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options: `All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality.` And ibid.: `Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use classes and css transitions:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.square').hover(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('square').addClass('left');
    });
});
```

```css
div.square {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
div.left {
    border-right: 100px solid red;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0;
    
    -webkit-transition: all  500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all  500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all  500ms ease-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
```